# Repeat table on every single page in rtf template

Tags: oracle, templates, ms-word, rtf

I am using the "Add-ins" plugin word 2010 to create rtf template for my application in Oracle. At preview, I want my head of the table to repeat on every single page from the source. I give you an example:

Column 1: No      Column 2: Student_Name    Column 3: Course

This head of table I want it to appear to top of every page. How should I do?

Comment: Create a Word document with a table with non-repeating headings. Save it as .rtf. Change the heading to repeat. Save it again. Compare the RTF. (Almost anyone here is likely to have to do the same to have a chance of answering your question!)

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in doing this too, I think the answer is to add the following to your header row

```
\trhdr
```

Table row header. This row should appear at the top of every page the current table appears on.
[Source](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)